# ImagePicker.openPicker is not working which i installed from react-native-customized-image-picker

Tags: react-native

**ERROR  TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeCustomizedImagePicker.default.openPicker')**

Comment: Can you please add your code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.